# Calling sub scripts from control script in Unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm working on a control script that calls multiple other sub-scripts. 
However, when I try to run one of the sub-scripts with arguments the script doesnt see the arguments

```
. ./subscript.sh var1 var2
```

when I reference $1 from the sub script "echo $1" it comes up blank

Initially I thought $1 from the sub script was referencing $1 from the control script but then I realised $1 from the control script has a value.

I'm not sure if it has to do with the method in which I am calling the sub scripts with the double dots.

```
. ./subscript.sh var1 var2
```

Help and suggestions are all welcome.

O.

Answer (score 0):

In ". ./subscript.sh var1 var2", the first dot include (source) the subscript in your script instead of executing it.

In other word, it add the lines of subscript.sh in your own script.

To have a separate execution, you need to call it directly:

```
./subscript.sh var1 var2
```

This way, the arguments will have the correct value.